# Including Angular-tree-component in project throws: (SystemJS) ctorParameters.map is not a function error in Console

Tags: angular

I refered [this](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs) to include the angular-tree-component plugin. I followed the exact steps and get following error while running the application:

Error: (SystemJS) ctorParameters.map is not a function(…)

My package.json file:

```
          {
            "name": "template2",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "scripts": {},
            "license": "ISC",
            "dependencies": {
              "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
              "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
              "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.1",
              "angular-tree-component": "3.6.0",
              "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
              "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
              "core-js": "^2.4.1",
              "ng-lightning": "^1.3.0",
              "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
              "ng2-dragula": "^1.3.1",
              "ng2-modal-dialog": "^1.0.1",
              "ngx-modal": "0.0.29",
              "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
              "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
              "systemjs": "0.19.39",
              "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
            },
            "devDependencies": {
              "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
              "typescript": "^2.0.3",
              "typings": "^1.4.0"
            }
          }
```

My Systemjs.config.js

```
            /**
             * System configuration for Angular samples
             * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
             */
            (function (global) {
                System.config({
                    paths: {
                        // paths serve as alias
                        'npm:': '/node_modules/',
                    },
                    // map tells the System loader where to look for things

                    //defaultJSExtensions: true,  // This is included for Model Popup
                    map: {
                        // our app is within the app folder
                        app: '/Scripts',
                        // angular bundles
                        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
                        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
                        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
                        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
                        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
                        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

                        /*The following is required by dragula */
                        'dragula': 'node_modules/dragula',
                        'ng2-dragula': 'node_modules/ng2-dragula',
                        'contra': 'node_modules/contra',
                        'atoa': 'node_modules/atoa',
                        'ticky': 'node_modules/ticky',
                        'crossvent': 'node_modules/crossvent/src',
                        'custom-event': 'node_modules/custom-event',
                        /*The following is required by dragula ^*/

                        'angular-tree-component': 'node_modules/angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.umd.js',


                        //The following is required by PopUp Model
                        "ngx-modal": "node_modules/ngx-modal",
                        // other libraries
                        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
                    },
                    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
                    packages: {
                        app: {
                            main: './main.js',
                            defaultExtension: 'js'
                        },
                        /*The following is required by dragula */
                        'dragula': { main: 'dragula.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'ng2-dragula': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'contra': { main: 'contra.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'atoa': { main: 'atoa.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'ticky': { main: 'ticky.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'crossvent': { main: 'crossvent.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        'custom-event': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
                        /*The following is required by dragula ^*/

                        'angular2-modal': { 
                            main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd',
                            defaultExtension: 'js'
                        },

                        "angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap": {
                            main: 'angular2-modal.bootstrap.umd',
                            defaultExtension: 'js'
                        },


                        "ngx-modal": { "main": "index.js", "defaultExtension": "js" },
                        rxjs: {
                            defaultExtension: 'js'
                        }
                    }
                });
            })(this);
```

I tried other plugins like Dragula and ngx-modal which seems to work fine. Is it something to do with the Angular-tree-component or is it just some build error?

Answer (score 0):

> update your Package.json file to latest stable version like I have used angular version 2.4.10 but you may use latest angular version 4.1.3 and its dependent compatible package version

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "2.4.10",
"@angular/common": "2.4.10",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.10",
"@angular/core": "2.4.10",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.10",
"@angular/http": "2.4.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.10",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.10",
"@angular/router": "3.0.1",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.63",
"angular-tree-component": "3.4.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"debug": "~2.6.3",
"ejs": "^2.3.3",
"express": "~4.15.2",
"rxjs": "^5.0.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
"twilio": "^2.11.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
}
```